Best way to read image captcha correctly and accurately

This is the image captcha for which I want to create a python code so that the captcha reader can read it effectively and efficiently.
I created a python code using pytesseract but it was reading the image ineffectively and giving the wrong sequence of characters.
This is the python code-
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageOps
import pytesseract

# Open the image file
image_path = "image.png"
image = Image.open(image_path)

# Preprocess the image
# Convert to grayscale
image = ImageOps.grayscale(image)

# Apply a median filter to remove noise
image = image.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter(size=3))

# Apply thresholding to get a binary image
threshold = 128
image = image.point(lambda p: p > threshold and 255)

# Perform OCR
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config='--psm 8')

print("Recognized text:", text)

Suggest me an alternative method or image recognition model so that I can read it properly. Which service would be best to read such a kind of captcha.

ok thank you. Got it!
